# Dynamic Way To Execute Code Based On Condition Statement C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm constructing some codes on C# to draw some lines but I'm able to modify the concept for a much simpler way as below for the question.

Inside the code there is a condition checking statement "**if (j == column)**", which the next condition checking is based on previous result. Is there any way that I can make the condition checking more dynamic/correct if I were to make the result as :

**Hello World 1**

(after some loop)

**Hello World 2**

(after some loop)

**Hello World 3**

(after some loop)

**Hello World 4**

Source code :

```
public static void Main()
    {
        int column = 7;
          for (int i = -1; i <= 7; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j < 28; j++)
                    {
                        if(j == column)
                            {
                               Console.WriteLine("Hello world 1");
                            column = column * 2;
                            }
                            if(j == column)
                            {
                               Console.WriteLine("Hello world 2");
                            column = column * 3;
                            }

                            if (j == column)
                            {
                               Console.WriteLine("Hello world 3");
                            column = column * 4;
                            }

                            if (j == column)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Hello world 4");
                                column = column * 5;
                            }

                    }
          }
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting twice `"Hello world 1"` as output

Answer (score 0):

Every time your for loop runs, it will at most match the first condition since you're updating the value of `column` but `j` remains the same in that iteration. Your code can be simplified to the following.

```
public static void Main()
    {
          int column = 7;
          for (int i = -1; i <= 7; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = -1; j < 28; j++)
                    {
                        if(j == column)
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine("Hello world 1");
                           column = column * 2;
                        }

                    }
          }
        }
```

But I don't believe this is your intention.

Comment: this is almost works for me, only that the int column does not seem to be updated to 14 after entering the if statement in my case. thank you